# Why we need to commit composer.lock file in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, composer

I am a little **confused regarding composer.json and composer.lock** file.I have read about composer and got when we commit code then it is necessary to push composer.lock file.I am not understanding why we need this while we can manage dependency by `composer.json` file?

If any body know about it then please explain it briefly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-without-composer-lock

> Committing this file to VC is important because it will cause anyone
>   who sets up the project to use the exact same versions of the
>   dependencies that you are using. Your CI server, production machines,
>   other developers in your team, everything and everyone runs on the
>   same dependencies, which mitigates the potential for bugs affecting
>   only some parts of the deployments.

Comment: Yes,I have read it,can you please update your answer in magento words with taking examples of versions ?

Comment: Ok! But, I'm working now. May I find an example and update my answer tonight.

Comment: Or, you can edit my answer with your example.